# Missing data from ADODB if the first 8 rows are empty

Tags: excel, vba, adodb, recordset

After days of testing, when I tried to copy data from one workbook to another using VBA ADODB connection,

I don't found the correct way, if it's possible to do.

My database wb comes from one extraction from SAP, so with one excel program I open this file, and using ADODB I choose some columns and, with copyfromrecordset i put the result on one sheet of my program.

Just now I have found that if the first eight records are empty the query don't extract records. It's possible!??!

I test this on much columns and at all I get the same result.

please see these pictures, they will explain better than my english (sorry)

as you can see the colum 4 and 5 aven't records
[image: First Test]

```
I add data on cells(8,4) and on cells(9,5)
all the record off column 4 now was extract
```

[image: Second Test]

```
In the third test I ad also value on cells(7,5)
and now in each columns I've the correct records
```

[image: third Test]

This is the query used on test:

```
Sub testQryResult()
Dim fNameAndPath As Variant
Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim strsql As String
Const adOpenStatic = 3
Const adLockOptimistic = 3
Const adCmdText = &H1
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

Set WsTo = ActiveWorkbook ' program sheet
    fNameAndPath = Application.GetOpenFilename(fileFilter:="Excel Files (*.XLSX), *.XLSX", Title:="Seleziona il file da importare")
    If fNameAndPath = False Then Exit Sub
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=fNameAndPath   'xls sheet with db from SAP

    Set WsFrom = ActiveWorkbook
    WsFrom.Activate

    cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & WsFrom.FullName & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;"";"
    strsql = "SELECT [(06)-Data creazione],[(07)-Inizio carico att],[(07)-Fine carico att], [(07)-Inizio trasp att], [(07)-Data FINE Sdoganamento],[(01-A)-Data di reg] from [Sheet1$];"
    rs.Open strsql, cn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText

    rs.MoveFirst
    dbSh.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs
    Else
    rs.MoveFirst
    WsTo.Sheets("ce").Range("O3").CopyFromRecordset rs

    Set rs = Nothing
    Set cn = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: I think to have found the solution, can be that some columns are extract from SAP as TEXT format also if thi contains number.
I changed the provider to:cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" & WsFrom.FullName & "; Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;"";" and now all records are extracted.

Comment: Maybe post your solution to an answer and accept it. It will be easier for future readers facing the same scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Even if I did not find a reason why the extraction didn't work, im not given up and I continued with the tests.

I found one old tread when one guy asking how to get data from qry from one column which contains both dates and numbers, one solution posted wah add IMEX=1 at connection string.

I Tryed but I get immediate error, so i tried with a different connection string using Microsoft.ACE instead Microsoft.Jet

```
cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" & WsFrom.FullName & "; Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;"";"
```

magically all data are extracted correctly, sure is not magic,and I'll find the technical reasons.

At the moment I post here my solution, with the hope of making time discounts to those who will find themselves with the same problem.

*...The three essential elements for getting anything worth having are; first, hard work, second, persistence, and third, common sense...*

Comment: I've been dealing with this bug for months at this point. Here are a few things I tried: explicitly setting column data types to text (`Range("A:A").NumberFormat = "Whatever"`), changing between `JET` and `ACE.OLEDB` connection strings, dynamically changing the IMEX type to scour the entire used-range (this is INCREDIBLY SLOW). I'm about to try just forcibly inserting data into the top row - I guess we'll see how that goes. Not sure how it's going to work with dates. This is such an annoying bug and there's next to no info online about how to consistently fix it. Wtf microsoft?

Comment: @Fabrizio: I am adding this comment on 28 June 2023 just for the record. I have come to the exact situation (First 8 rows blank and query record count result is -1). The above solution does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same problem. Technically, I can't explain what the reason is. When an Excel workbook is open, the data is loaded correctly. If the book is closed, I get Null. In my case, the problem was the format of the data on the sheet. There was a numeric column with text data, I set the general format and all the data loaded correctly with the file on and off, despite the large number of rows at the top of the table.

Comment: The OP answered his own question in the comments.